# Unfamiliar notation in manpage mmap(2): void addr[.length]

Tags: mmap, manpage

What does the notation `void addr[.length]` in `mmap(2)` mean? I could interpret `void *addr` or `size_t length`, but what is the semantics of this "mixed" notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [solved this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=284636) for me after all: `void addr[.length]` is a common reference to alternative ways for passing an array:

```
int foo(void *addr);
int foo(void addr[]);
int foo(void addr[10]);
```